# Is it possible to train in certain stats to influence stat growth?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

EV Training is a term used in the Pokemon games which essentially refers to going into combat against certain enemies who give specific stat growths.
For example, a [Pikachu gives 2 Speed EVs](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/025.shtml), where a [Haunter gives 2 Sp. Attack EVs](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/093.shtml).

I was wondering if there is anything relatable to FE: Heroes,
for example does killing a Armoured unit give a better chance at getting +1 Def on level up?  Or does killing an enemy Hero (as opposed to an unnamed unit) grant better bonuses upon leveling up?

Another thing I noticed is that units tend to gain more stats if they level up during a harder encounter, for example I did a level 20 Training Stratum with my team at an average level of 15 and they seemed to get more stat increases when they leveled up, however this could just be a fluke.

In short, **does the type of enemy and level of enemy affect the stat growth of your characters when they level up?**

Comment: As soon as someone compared FE's stat system to IV's, I knew someone was going to ask about EV's.  **FE is not Pokemon**.

Comment: Whoa why the downvotes? How can I make this question better? I know its not pokemon, but I was wondering if it was possible that they were affected. What is wrong with that? :(

Comment: I did not vote on this, but if I had to guess it would be because no Fire Emblem game has ever worked this way -- stats have always been RNG-based and have had nothing to do with player behavior. Even though the system is different for Heroes, since it's a simplified mobile version of the main series, it would not make sense to change the mechanics on such a fundamental level like this. Also, as @Frank said, Fire Emblem isn't Pokémon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not how leveling up in Fire Emblem has worked in any game, including Heroes. In fact, in Heroes, the stats are determined when the hero is obtained. From [this article](https://rankedboost.com/fire-emblem-heroes/stats/):

> Unit Stats like ATK and DEF and others are distributed randomly, this means some players may have a LVL 8 Anna Unit with 12 ATK while others will have 16 ATK. **These Fire Emblem Heroes Stat differences are predetermined when the Hero is drawn/obtained.**

The [wiki](http://feheroes.wiki/Stat_Growth) also explains how the Stat Growth mechanics work in Heroes:

> Stat values in Fire Emblem Heroes are semi-random. The base level 1 stats are rolled randomly, but max level stats are predetermined based on those initial base stat rolls. **Even though stat growth per level looks random, the stats will always converge onto the predetermined max level values.**

Thus, there is no way to influence stats by training a character against a specific type of enemy.

This can also be proven by having your character level up on one type of enemy in a mission, die before that mission ends (will cause the character to lose gained EXP and revert back to the level they started the mission at), then have them level up by fighting a different type of enemy. The stat growths will be identical regardless of who or what they fought in order to level up.